# Shell Scripting :: Allow User in One Shell to Run App from Another User in a Different Shell?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have an unusual question.  In an Ubuntu environment (ver 16.04), how can a user in one shell run a program that's been installed by a user in another shell?  Crudely put:

```
USER_A                                   USER_B
-----------------------      ===>>       ---------------
/usr/sbin/nologin shell                  /bin/bash shell
```

where `USER_B` has installed some app, and that app can only be run by him.

So here's some more specific detail.  On my Ubuntu machine, I'm running Apache2 ver 2.4.41.  When you run Apache on your server, a `www-data` user is created for running your webpages, I guess.  The `www-data` user runs in a `/usr/sbin/nologin` shell:

```
pete@myUbuntu$ sudo finger www-data
Login: www-data                         Name: www-data
Directory: /var/www                     Shell: /usr/sbin/nologin    <<=======
Never logged in.
No mail.
No Plan.
pete@myUbuntu$
```

So `www-data` is `USER_A`.  I don't really know what the `/usr/sbin/nologin` shell is, but it seems significant.

Apache2 hosts a webpage, and that webpage runs a script.  This means from Ubuntu's perspective, user `www-data` is running the script.  The script must run an application that was installed by another user, user `pete`.  Here's his profile:

```
pete@myUbuntu$ sudo finger pete
Login: pete                          Name: Pete Smith
Directory: /home/pete                Shell: /bin/bash    <<=======
Never logged in.
No mail.
No Plan.
pete@myUbuntu$
```

User `pete`'s shell is `/bin/bash`, which is not the same as user `www-data`.  I'm betting this is why `www-data`'s script can't run `pete`'s application.  Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/pete
whoami
pwd
/bin/bash    

# Try:
{
    sudo -i -u pete database_lookup_app.sh
} || {
    # Catch:
    echo "ERROR :: Unable to run database_lookup_app.sh"
}
```

When the script is run, the output on my webpage is:

```
www-data
/home/pete
ERROR :: Unable to run database_lookup_app.sh
```

Ugh!  You see the problem.

I've been playing around with this, trying to figure out what I have to do to allow `www-data` to be allowed to run `database_lookup_app.sh`.  I don't think it is a permissions thing, because both users `pete` and `www-data` have been added to a common user group.  I've also added both users to the visudo file:

```
pete     ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

There's gotta be a way to do this.  Any thoughts?

Comment: `installed by a user in another shell` you can't "install" something "in shell". `Ugh! You see the problem.` your sudo configuration requires to type a password.  Also, the script `database_lookup_app.sh` could  have run and failed, ergo the error. Remove `-i`, specify the shell and path explicitly, add NOPASSWD, and redirect stderr to stdout in your script `exec 2>&1` and see the errors. `the script is run, the output on my webpage` how is it run?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks Kamil!  My command in the script is now:  >>sudo -u pete --shell /bin/hash /home/pete/database_lookup_app.sh  exec 2>&1<<  And I've changed the visudo entry to this:  >>www-data ALL=(ph9821) NOPASSWD: /home/ph9821/testCode/git/NDaaS_RestAPIs/mvn<<

Comment: @KamilCuk  I now get this error:  [[sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper]]  So you're right, the command is failing because of a password issue!  That's useful information.

Comment: @KamilCuk  The website I mentioned in the post allows the users to upload a file.  When they do, the HTML / PHP code automatically runs this shell script.  That's what I meant by "the script is run, the output on my webpage is..."  The output is displayed directly on the HTML webpage.  Not the best way to work, but it'll do...

Comment: `The website I mentioned` I wasn't aware of that. `allows the users to upload a file` this sounds extremely dangerous. Consider using php, it has maximum limits and directory restrictions. Consider using `ssh`, it has security and encryption. Remove `--shell` option - you are not running an interactive shell. Also, remove `exec` or put it before the command. Do not copy code from Internet without understanding.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you, I appreciate your advice and caution.  FYI: I'm working to develop a tool for my teammates at work, about 5 of us.  I've created a custom database Java program that takes an XLSX file as input.  Rather than have them send me their input files via email and I run the code on my laptop, the hope is that they can upload their files to this little webserver, have the script run the code automatically, and I am left alone.  So I'm not overly concerned by security.  I'll implement your suggestions.  :)